# How to define Python 'Missing' type annotation?

Tags: python, python-typing

let's say I have a simple HTTP endpoint accepting JSON payload form the user:

- here the user passed `None` explicitly:

```json
payload = {
    "name": "Paul",
    "option": None
}
```

- and here the user didn't provide `option` at all:

```json
payload = {
    "name": "Paul",
}
```

For some reason, I want to 'normalize' such payloads into

```py
payload = {
    "name": "Paul",
    "option": Missing(),
}
```

where `Missing()` is an instance of a class:

```py
class Missing:
    """Represents missing value in a dictionary"""
    pass
```

so I can differentiate between user passing `None` explicitly and not passing `option` key at all.
What I'm struggling to define is a custom "type constructor", such that I could then annotate function argument like so:

```py
def process_user_option(option: Missing[Optional[str]]):
   ...do something with 'option'
```

and the semantics of `Missing` would be something like this:

```py
Missing(x) -> Union[Optional[x], Missing]
```

Any suggestions? Thank you!

Comment: Perhaps I'm missing the point, but it sounds like `Union[Optional[x], Missing]` (or, more concisely in Python 3.10+, `x | None | Missing`) is exactly the type you want.

Comment: @SilvioMayolo correct, however I wanted to learn how to create such custom "type constructors"

Answer (score 1):

One suggestion:

```py
from typing import  NewType, Optional, TypeVar

class MissingType: pass
Missing = MissingType()

T = TypeVar('T')
PossiblyMissing = T | MissingType


Name   = NewType("Name", str)
Option = NewType("Option", dict)

def process_user_option(option: PossiblyMissing[Optional[Option]]):
    if option is Missing:
        ...

    if option is None:
        ...
```

Answer (score 1):

Additionally, you might want to declare optional keys in a `TypedDict` explicitly with [`total=False`](https://mypy.readthedocs.io/en/stable/more_types.html#totality)*.

```py
from typing import TypedDict


class _PayloadBase(TypedDict):
    name: str


class Payload(_PayloadBase, total=False):
    option: Optional[str]  # optional key
```

in order to safely normalize and process the payload:

```py
@final
class MissingType:
    pass


Missing = MissingType()


class NormalizedPaylaod(_PayloadBase):
    option: str | MissingType


def normalize_payload(payload: Payload) -> NormalizedPaylaod:
    option = Missing if (option := payload.get("option")) is None else option
    normalized_payload: NormalizedPaylaod = {
        "name": payload["name"],
        "option": option,
    }
    return normalized_payload


def process_payload(payload: NormalizedPaylaod) -> None:
    if payload["option"] is Missing:
        print("No option specified!")
```

*It will be much easier in Python 3.11 with [PEP-655](https://peps.python.org/pep-0655/) (`Required` and `NotRequired`).

Comment: didn't know about PEP 655, thanks!